# Can I make a circle/table graphic in SSRS and divide it by a passed number

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, graphics, visualization, pie-chart

I was asked to create a report (in SSRS visual studio 2019).

The report has the following table number, numeric. How many people per table (generally 4-12), names, etc and the order in which the people will sit. From this I'm being asked to create is a graphic visualization of a circle (broken out evenly by number of guests per table) in the order of which they are seated.

For example here is my data set:

[image]

I need to create a seprate page with the lists below so it would like like this

Page 1 would have this:
Table 1 - 8 Guests

[image]
[image]

Page 2 would have this:
Table 2 - 4 Guests

[image]
[image]

we can also use embedded images -- the team has an image for each table size but we still have to obtain the locations of each spot (which means we'd have to know how to divide a circle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily.

Add a list or single column table and the set `Dataset` property to your dataset name.

Change the row group (probably called "details") by adding a group that groups by `table`.

Now insert a pie chart into the table cell. We should now get 1 pie chart per table.

Click the pie chart and add a value entry, set the value expression to `=1/countrows()`, this bit will just split the chart up evenly based on the number of guests.

Set the category group to the guest field.

Right-click the chart and "Show data labels", then right-click the label and set the value to this expression `=Fields!id.Value & " - " & Fields!guest.Value`. Set the data label `position` property to "outside".

Finally click the chart and expand the "custom attributes" section, set the `PieStartAngle` property to 270, this will make sure the first person is immediately after the 12 o'clock position.

Oh,. and set the chart title to something like `="Table " & Fields!table.Value"

The final output looks like this...

[image]

Comment: do you know where I can look to adjust the padding on the chart. I set it up to have the text on the outside with your instructions (thank you very much for them). It looks as though there is a huge space at the top and bottom of the graph (legend is at the bottom and looks fine). I cant find this setting

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean but look in the chart properties, not the GUI version , the properties panel which you can access using F4 in Visual Studio (I think it's a menu option in in Report Builder) There are lots of custom properties in there, some of them allow you to set a specific size a position of the chart body but I can't remember exactly what they are. If you are still stuck, start a new question and show and example of what you mean.